# move HashMap entry from source to destination contained in a 2D vector

Tags: rust

How to transfer a `HashMap` entry from source to detination which are part of the same 2D vector.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut grid: Vec<Vec<HashMap<i32, i32>>> = vec![vec![HashMap::new(); 100 as usize]; 100 as usize];
    
    let from = &mut grid[23][56];
    let to = &mut grid[32][65];
    
    let k = 6;
    let from_entry = from.remove_entry(&k);
    if let Some((k, v)) = from_entry {
        to.insert(k, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: just inline the from and to variables

Comment: Or even just move the `to` below `from_entry`: `remove_entry` *moves* the entry out of the map, so the `from` borrow becomes unnecessary. The one issue with both changes is that if the indexes are out of bounds the resolution of `to` panics, and the entry is lost.

Comment: To solve that you need to use the `split_*_mut` methods (or iterators) to borrow the two hashmaps concurrently. AFAIK the stdlib still has no shortcut to get a pair of mutable references out of a slice directly.